# How to make my Twitter bot only reply to recent tweets

Tags: python, twitter

I've been trying to learn how to make a twitter bot and I made a simple search and reply bot, it searches for whenever someone tweets my name and it replies, however my bot has been replying to the same tweets over and over again. I tried to add a since variable in the loop that updates whenever I reply to a tweet by said tweet's ID then I refined the search query with a since_id = since but that did nothing, any suggestions ? here's my code :

```
import os
import random
import tweepy

consumer_key = os.environ.get('TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY')
consumer_secret = os.environ.get('TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET')
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
access_token = os.environ.get('TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN')
access_token_secret = os.environ.get('TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET')
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
replies = ["example 1", 
           "example 2", 
           "example 3"
          ]  
if __name__ == "__main__":
twitter = TwitterAPI()
since = 0
while True:
    tweets = api.search(q="shalash -shalashtein -OsamaAhmadSalas -ShalashteinBot -ghghgu38678638 -athy_shalash",since_id=since) #I added these exclusions because the bot was searching screen names too 
    for s in tweets:
        since = s.id
        rand = random.choice(replies)
        sn = s.user.screen_name
        m = "@%s %s" % (sn,rand)
        s = api.update_status(m, s.id)
    time.sleep(60)
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the tweets you've answered to to a DB or in a text file, then just check if you already answered it.